# Git : Files a appears twice in index

Tags: git

I have trouble removing files in git.
The problem is that the files appears twice in the index (in source tree).

If i try to remove one reference, then the file appears both in staged files and unstaged file.

I am getting an error (the file does not exists) when doing actions on the remaining git references.

How can i clean the index for those files?

Here is a screenshot from source tree (sorry not enough reputation to embed the image directly):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj83u.png

Here is the output of git status:
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'GitLab/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

```
modified:   External OSX/PhFacebook (modified content, untracked content)
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Thanks

Comment: Screenshots, please.

Comment: Can you also provide the results of `git status` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

do a git reset:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

it will clean your staging area and working directory.

#### ***[`git reset HEAD --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your head back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts, if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

---

This schema illustrate which command does what.
As you can see there `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Comment: But why did the problem occur?

Comment: This is how the 3-states work in git. You can have separate content for each file in any of the 3-states (repo, staging area, working directory).

You cadded file and then you re-modified it so you see it on both the working directory and the staging area